# Set notification icons to show all in Unity-2D

Tags: indicator, unity-2d, notification

I can't get Unity-2D to show all notification icons with dconf-editor. It only changes it on unity-3D. Is there a way to get it to work on unity 2D?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are talking about "notifications" and not "indicators". Indicators are supposed to work out of the box in Ubuntu as well as in Ubuntu 2D. Notifications are still used in older programs and you can use Dconf Editor to enable them.

I cannot test your problem on my own computer since I cannot find any program that still uses notifications. But I still advice you to try successively the 2 methods given on [this page of WebUpd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-re-enable-notification-area.html): the method with Dconf Editor and the one with the command line.

If it does not work, please edit your question to indicate what you did and correct the difference between indicators and notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Support in unity-2d for the systray is not so great unless -

If you are on 11.10 & update to the latest unity-2d thru the daily ppa then you can get decent support

Bug discussing - 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/847525

daily ppa  - https://launchpad.net/~unity-2d-team/+archive/unity-2d-daily

Though there still seems to be a **possible** issue  -

unity-2d should show any app that is white-listed in unity, but in tests that doesn't always work.

Instead it appears that the unity systray-whitelist may need to be set to 'all' for many systray icons to appear in unity-2d.

A couple of examples here where specifically white-listing does Not work in unity-2d, but using 'all' does, I'm sure there are others -

audacious; wicd

To set the unity systray-whitelist to 'all' this command will do so, though one may wish to do this graphically thru dconf-editor. If so, it's part of dconf-tools, the location is -

desktop > unity > panel

Anyway command to set to 'all' if desired or needed,  a log out/in afterwards -

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel  systray-whitelist "['all']"
```

Personally my preference is **not** to use 'all', particularly if also using unity-3d, YMMV

Comment: i did ["all"] and it still doesn't work